# Unable to set Selected List Item of RadioButtionList dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.net Radio Button List in my aspx page with two list items and values of these list items are "1","0" respectively. I am getting some values from database and performing some condition on that data to set selection of list item on the basis of those condition. Code is working properly but list item selection is not performed when i saw the output on the browser.

```
ASPX Page Control:

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rg_A1S1Q1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Server Side Coding:

RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)cph.FindControl("rg_A1S1Q1");
rbl.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
rbl.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color: blue");
rbl.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rbl.SelectedValue = "1";
```

Comment: thanx for reply...but code is Not Working....